# Как создать EXE-исполняемый файл для Windows, из-под Linux дистрибутива?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, кросс-компиляция

У меня есть исходный код программы, написанный на Python. Как я могу получить исполняемый exe-файл для запуска на Windows?

Пробовал использовать Pyinstaller как на Win так и на Linux. На windows довольно проблематично установить все необходимые пакеты python, Visual Studio, и т д. А на Linux Pyinstaller собирает исполняемый файл для linux, но не для windows

Comment: Единственным выходом для меня стала установка VirtualBox + Python + PyInstaller. На моей станции также имеется и Wine + Python + PyInstaller, но заставить что-то собрать PyInstaller из под Wine я так и не смог, потратив на это 16 часов, пробуя различные версии Python, PyInstaller и Wine, гремя бубном и тряся булками...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyinstaller перестал поддерживать компиляцию кода для сторонних операционных систем.

Решение вопроса: установка более ранних версий pyinstaller'a из [официального сайта](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases)

Однако в таком случае, работоспособность не гарантирована. Но мне помогло